# How to use XPATH functions in Mule

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, mule, mule-studio

I have an input SOAP XML as follows :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:retrieveDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>662</v1:Id>
      </v1:retrieveDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now my question is simple ...

How can I use XPATH functions like count(),name(),substring() etc in Mule

I want to use XPATH on this SOAP request like the following :-

```
 <logger message="#[xpath('count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

But It is throwing following exception :-

```
Exception stack is:
1. No Such Function {http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core}:count (org.jaxen.UnresolvableException)
  org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext:127 (null)
2. Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)" (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)
  org.mule.module.xml.expression.AbstractXPathExpressionEvaluator:141 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleRuntimeException.html)
3. org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)" (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  org.mule.module.xml.el.XPathFunction:70 (null)
4. [Error: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)"]
[Near : {... xpath('count(//v1:retrieveData ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1] (org.mule.mvel2.CompileException)
  org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer:437 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/mvel2/CompileException.html)
5. Execution of the expression "xpath('count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:202 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
6. Execution of the expression "xpath('count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function {http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core}:count
    at org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext.getFunction(SimpleFunctionContext.java:127)
    at org.jaxen.ContextSupport.getFunction(ContextSupport.java:242)
    at org.jaxen.Context.getFunction(Context.java:216)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

**Please note** :- I have already used **Mule namespace-manager** as following :-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="v1" uri="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

and I am getting results for the following :-  `<logger message="#[xpath('//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id').text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant bit of the exception, which you are not showing above, is:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function {http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core}:count
at org.jaxen.SimpleFunctionContext.getFunction(SimpleFunctionContext.java:127)
at org.jaxen.ContextSupport.getFunction(ContextSupport.java:242)
at org.jaxen.Context.getFunction(Context.java:216)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

As you can see, the `count` XPath function is evaluated in the Mule namespace. This is a side-effect of using `includeConfigNamespaces="true"` in your `namespace-manager`. You don't seem to need the Mule namespaces to evaluate your XPath (you're not using any Mule namespaces in your SOAP messages), so you should set this value to false.

This will be fixed in Mule 3.6, per [MULE-7030](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7030).

Comment: Great ... Thanks David ... I have updated the question with exception

Answer (score 1):

So, as per David's suggestion .. the final working solution is setting `includeConfigNamespaces="false"` :-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="false">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="v1" uri="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

So now, I can use XPATH functions like `count()` without any issue now :-

```
<logger message="#[xpath('count(//v1:retrieveDataRequest/v1:Id)')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```